# Randomized data after grouping them

Tags: mysql, sql, random, group-by

I want to randomized my data after grouping them. How I can achieve that in elegant way ?

Here I have created [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8b81/1).

**Expected Results**,

Gold, Gold 2, Gold 3, Silver 3, Silver, Bronze

Gold 2, Gold 3, Gold, Silver, Silver 3, Bronze

Gold, Gold 3, Gold 2, Silver, Silver 3, Bronze

Bronze, Silver 3, Silver, Gold 2, Gold, Gold 3 etc....

In brief it should **group them first alphabetically (name) and then randomized internally grouped data**.

I tried,

> SELECT * FROM `type` ORDER BY name, RAND()

This do order by name but not randomize them.

> SELECT * FROM `type` GROUP BY name ORDER BY RAND()

This randomized the data but not grouping them.

Comment: You Randomize and again show all? Why so

Comment: I want to shuffle type in groups.

Comment: try `ORDER BY `name` ASC` : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8b81/10

Comment: @diEcho - Should shuffle on each run. See the expected results I posted.

Comment: I didn't get the 'expected results' algorithm

Comment: @diEcho: Gold are grouped and randomised. Then Silver are grouped and randomised. And so on ... This is what OP is expecting.

Comment: @Ravinder - Thanks for adding more explanation.

Comment: I think your wording is very misleading. That's not true sql group-by, but you just want to **group by first word alphabetically then randomize order per group**

Comment: even alphabetically its not the right order .. it would be Bronze Gold silver

Comment: @diEcho - It does not matter it will be fine if the order is like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`substring_index(col, ' ', 1)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to split the string value by single space delimiter and get the first token and use this as your first order criteria. On your second order criteria use `rand()` so that names that have equal first word are randomized

```
select name
from type
order by substring_index(name, ' ', 1), rand()
```

The assumption here is words on your name column always delimited by single space

**Edit**
Following are more examples on `substring_index`:

```
select substring_index('hello world', ' ', 1); -- 'hello'
select substring_index('hello', ' ', 1); -- 'hello'
select substring_index('hello_world foo', ' ', 1); -- 'hello_world'
select substring_index('yippie ki yay', ' ', 2); -- 'yippie ki'
```

Comment: I'm just curious that how this works, a order by create a virtual column with data of `substring_index(name, ' ', 1)` ?

Comment: No virtual column is created. The dbms just uses the first token of the word to order it. Instead of ordering it using 'Gold', 'Gold 2', 'Bronze' it now sees 'Gold', 'Gold', 'Bronze'

Comment: @gerrytan - True but if we give that words directly to order clause without using substring function it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `substr` will benefit performance if you know maximum character in `name` you want to order:

```
SELECT * FROM type ORDER BY substr(name,1,4), rand();
```

And from @gerrytan's above answer, use substring_index for real life desired result.

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8b81/48)

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT * FROM `type` ORDER BY `name`, `name` RLIKE '^.[:num]+$', RAND();
```

[`SQL DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8b81/51)